# How can I split the xml file using regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Here

```
<root>
    <SchoolOrInstitution schoolType="highschool">
        <SchoolName>BUTLER HIGH SCHOOL</SchoolName>
        <Degree degreeType="highschool"/>
    </SchoolOrInstitution>
    <SchoolOrInstitution schoolType="highschool">
        <SchoolName>BUTLER HIGH SCHOOL</SchoolName>
        <Degree degreeType="highschool"/>
    </SchoolOrInstitution>
    <SchoolOrInstitution schoolType="highschool">
        <SchoolName>BUTLER HIGH SCHOOL</SchoolName>
        <Degree degreeType="highschool"/>
    </SchoolOrInstitution>
    ..............
</root>
```

I want to split this xml in to mutiple file based on the number of `SchoolOrInstitution` tag.

Each XML should have 3 such tag.

So if the mail file has 9 `SchoolOrInstitution` tags, it should create 3 child file.

And `root` tag will also assign to to all the 3 files.

Comment: Euhm I would think that perl has more than enough XML parsers ? Otherwise, what have you tried ?

Comment: I have pretty less years of experience in perl. Please tell me some solution.

Comment: Well then, now is the time to learn. A couple of search queries and the documentation at your side should get you quite far.

Comment: Please give me some start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xml_split` is a tool that comes with [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) that seems quite close to what you are looking for. `xml_split -g3 -l1 my.xml` will get you most of the way, the only difference being that the top level element will have a tag name that's assigned by the tool instead of being the original name.

Comment: When I try this command, I am getting this error `cannot create main file 'E:Jitterbitshare♀ritolaymy1-00.xml': Invalid argument a
t C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin/xml_split line 162.`

Comment: do you have permission to write in the directory in which you're working?

Comment: Good to see you here @mirod. I saw you that you are the owner of twig. Keep it up.

Answer (score 4):

Using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
my $old := open 19741254.xml ;
my $n = 1;
while $old/root/SchoolOrInstitution[1] {
      my $new := create root ;
      xmv $old/root/SchoolOrInstitution[position() <= 3] into $new/root ;
      save :f concat($n, '.xml') $new ;
      $n = $n + 1 ;
}
```